# 500 - An error has occurred. in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla2.5, administrator

when I try to login to Joomla from backend it gives the following problem,
500 - An error has occurred. I have changed file permissions to 777 for tmp,logs,cache,administrator/cache. Still i'm getting the same problem.

Please help,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you made any changes to your .htaccess file?

Comment: No Brother I didn't Changed Anything other than file permissions

Comment: You need to look at your web server's log to see the actual error message. Please don't just guess.

Comment: Hi Vicario, Where can I Find web server's log file?

Comment: It depends on the server software (Apache, IIS, Nginx...), the platform (Linux, FreeBSD, Windows...) and the specific settings.

Comment: Hi Vicario, I'm Using Joomla 2.5, apache2.2 , PHP 4.5. Windows7 Os.

Answer (score 0):

check your configuration.php file to see if you have correct paths here

```
public $log_path = '........check this path........../logs';
public $tmp_path = '........check this path........../tmp';
```

Regards
George